# Invoke and task not working

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I'm writing a program in C # and I have a problem that I want to update Label and ProgressBar on view from a method which is in different class after each loop. It updates these controls, however, not after each loop but at the end of the method. How to solve it? Task.Run (() => methodFromAnotherClass ()) does not work at all, and when I use Invoke.Dispatcher and when I pass the controls as parameters to the method, the update takes place only at the end of the method, and not after each loop.

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FindDocument findDocument = new FindDocument(labelCurrentNumber, progressBar1);
    cProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>();
    progress.ProgressChanged += (p, value) => { progressBar1.Value = value; labelCurrentNumber.Content = value.ToString(); };
    //Task.Run(() => findDocument.Find(csvRows, mode, (int)slider.Value, 1, check, progress, outputFileCsv));
    findDocument.Find(csvRows, mode, (int)slider.Value, 1, 1, progress, outputFileCsv);
}
```

Above is code from view.

```
public int Find(List<CsvModel> csvRows, SearchMode PageMode, int PageMargin, double sensitivity, int pageInfo, IProgress<int> progress, string outPath)
{
    csvContent.AppendLine("sep=,");
    csvContent.AppendLine("Lp,Plik wejściowy, Plik wyjściowy, Wynik");

    foreach (CsvModel csv in csvRows)
    {
        progressReport++;
        progress.Report(progressReport);

        lab.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => lab.Content = progressReport.ToString());
        this.lab.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send, new Action(() => lab.Content = progressReport));
    }
    File.WriteAllText(outPath + @"\dane.csv", csvContent.ToString());
    logger.Info($"Zakończono przetwarzanie obrazu");
    return 0;
}
```

Above is code from another class which method gives as parameters controls.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Program does not even call this method. When I set a breakpoint in this method with Task.Run() program even does not go inside this method.

Comment: Bear in mind that UI elements are not thread safe. And have you tried using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem();` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you run this synchronously (like you currently do) UI is blocked until the end of method so you do not see progress change.

If you use Task, you probably get error because I do not believe `progress.ProgressChanged` is thread safe. You could use `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Contorl.Invoke` when reporting progress `( progress.Report(progressReport);)` or in event itself `(progressBar1.Value = value; labelCurrentNumber.Content = value.ToString();)`

Comment: I changed this to Dispatcher.Invoke for progressBar and Label and still don`t work. I do not use progress.Report. Still UI is like blocked or something. I can see changes only after method stop working but during work view is not changing.

Comment: Maybe this method is too fast? Try adding some delay (Thread.Sleep(100)) in foreach loop and see what happens.

Comment: This is not problem with speed. The whole problem is that when I call Task.Run, the function is not called at all but when i Call fucntion without Task.Run it works but UI is blocked to method stop working